How to disable inactive tab discarding in Chrome 127+
I am developing an extension for chrome that should periodically receive some information from the server and update the data on the page. Everything works fine while the tab is active, but when it becomes inactive, everything related to setInterval works much slower.
The extension will work on a system where I have administrator rights and full access to the browser settings and I want to understand how to disable tab discarding for the browser completely and allow the extension to work normally on an inactive tab.
I tried to turn off Auto Discardable in chrome://discards on Chrome 127 on Windows and Ubuntu, but it doesn't work and after a while the extension starts working with delays. Using chrome.alarms does not allow me to receive data every 10 seconds, and besides, everything that uses setInterval in my extension slows down anyway so extension doesn't work fast enough.

It's timer throttling, not tab discarding. Since it only applies to web pages, you can use a timer in your 1) extension's background script or 2) offscreen document and send a message to your content script. In case 2 you'll use chrome.runtime.connect in the content script and chrome.runtime.onConnect in the offscreen document, then port.postMessage inside the timer.
